# Use a svg image to drag along a line in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to build a visualization in D3.js that illustrates the concept of potential energy and kinetic energy for my students. In essence, I want the students to be able to drag a skier up a slope (i.e. a Line) and when they drop him, he transits down again. I'm sure it is an easy task in D3 but I'm struggling to understand how I can get the skier icon to be draggable only along the line path?

Here's an image for illustration:

[image]

I want the skier icon to switch place with the ball with the green connector. I have used
https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/closest-point-on-line as inspiration for this project. Here, you can drag the circle up and down but the small ball will always be on that line. I want the same thing with my skier but I'm struggling to understand how I can accomplish this?

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ey69b415/).

```js
const height = 500;
const width = 960;
const skierIconSvg = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/94/94150.svg";


const [p1, p2, p3] = [
  [width / 3, 213],
  [(2 * width) / 3, 300],
  [width / 2, 132],
];

const svg = d3.select('svg');

const line = svg.append('line').attr('stroke', 'black');

const connection = svg.append('line').attr('stroke', 'green');

const projection = svg
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 5)
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('fill', 'none');

const skier = svg
  .append('image')
  .attr('id', 'skier')
  .attr('href', skierIconSvg)
  .attr('x', -40)
  .attr('y', -80)
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100);

const point = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('cursor', 'move')
  .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
  .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
  .attr('stroke-width', 30)
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data([p1, p2, p3])
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 10)
  .attr('fill', (d, i) => (i === 2 ? 'red' : null))
  .call(
    d3
    .drag()
    .subject(([x, y]) => ({
      x,
      y
    }))
    .on('drag', dragged)
  );

update();

function dragged(d) {
  d[0] = d3.event.x;
  d[1] = d3.event.y;
  update();
}

function update() {
  const t = (width + height) / distance(p1, p2);
  const l1 = interpolate(p1, p2, t);
  const l2 = interpolate(p2, p1, t);
  const p = interpolate(p1, p2, project(p1, p2, p3));
  connection.attr('x1', p3[0]).attr('y1', p3[1]);
  connection.attr('x2', p[0]).attr('y2', p[1]);
  projection.attr('cx', p[0]).attr('cy', p[1]);
  line.attr('x1', l1[0]).attr('y1', l1[1]);
  line.attr('x2', l2[0]).attr('y2', l2[1]);
  point.attr('cx', (d) => d[0]).attr('cy', (d) => d[1]);
  //skier.attr('x', (d) => d[0]).attr('y', (d) => d[1]);
}

function distance([x1, y1], [x2, y2]) {
  return Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2);
}

function interpolate([x1, y1], [x2, y2], t) {
  return [x1 + (x2 - x1) * t, y1 + (y2 - y1) * t];
}

function project([x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]) {
  const x21 = x2 - x1,
    y21 = y2 - y1;
  const x31 = x3 - x1,
    y31 = y3 - y1;
  return (x31 * x21 + y31 * y21) / (x21 * x21 + y21 * y21);
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

circle {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-axis.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Forsøk på å lage en tutorial i JavaScript og D3.js</h1>
  <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close! The only thing I did was draw two circles instead of three, and give the skier the coordinates of the last circle. Then I applied `transform` to the skier, because otherwise he would be anchored at the top left of the image, instead of the bottom centre.

I used `datum` instead of `data`, since `datum` only expects one value, while `data` expects an array. See [this bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/hugolpz/824446bb2f9bc8cce607) for a good tutorial on it.

```js
const height = 500;
const width = 960;
const skierIconSvg = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/94/94150.svg";


const [p1, p2, p3] = [
  [width / 3, 213],
  [(2 * width) / 3, 300],
  [width / 2, 132],
];

const svg = d3.select('svg');

const line = svg
  .append('line')
  .attr('stroke', 'black');

const connection = svg
  .append('line')
  .attr('stroke', 'green');

const projection = svg
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 5)
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('fill', 'none');

const g = svg
  .append('g')
  .attr('cursor', 'move')
  .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
  .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
  .attr('stroke-width', 30);

const point = g
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data([p1, p2])
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 10)
  .call(
    d3
    .drag()
    .subject(([x, y]) => ({
      x,
      y
    }))
    .on('drag', dragged)
  );

const skier = g
  .append('image')
  .attr('id', 'skier')
  .datum(p3)
  .attr('href', skierIconSvg)
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .attr("transform", "translate(-50, -100)")
  .call(
    d3
    .drag()
    .subject(([x, y]) => ({
      x,
      y
    }))
    .on('drag', dragged)
  );

update();

function dragged(d) {
  d[0] = d3.event.x;
  d[1] = d3.event.y;
  update();
}

function update() {
  const t = (width + height) / distance(p1, p2);
  const l1 = interpolate(p1, p2, t);
  const l2 = interpolate(p2, p1, t);
  const p = interpolate(p1, p2, project(p1, p2, p3));
  connection.attr('x1', p3[0]).attr('y1', p3[1]);
  connection.attr('x2', p[0]).attr('y2', p[1]);
  projection.attr('cx', p[0]).attr('cy', p[1]);
  line.attr('x1', l1[0]).attr('y1', l1[1]);
  line.attr('x2', l2[0]).attr('y2', l2[1]);
  point.attr('cx', (d) => d[0]).attr('cy', (d) => d[1]);
  skier.attr('x', (d) => d[0]).attr('y', (d) => d[1]);
}

function distance([x1, y1], [x2, y2]) {
  return Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2);
}

function interpolate([x1, y1], [x2, y2], t) {
  return [x1 + (x2 - x1) * t, y1 + (y2 - y1) * t];
}

function project([x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]) {
  const x21 = x2 - x1,
    y21 = y2 - y1;
  const x31 = x3 - x1,
    y31 = y3 - y1;
  return (x31 * x21 + y31 * y21) / (x21 * x21 + y21 * y21);
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

circle {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-path.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-shape.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-axis.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Forsøk på å lage en tutorial i JavaScript og D3.js</h1>
  <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cheers. Now I understand a bit more. Is there also a way in which I can calculate where the skier is on the line when you drag him up and down, like a tooltip or something similar, or is this too complex?

Comment: Well, all you need to do that is get the distance from the `projection` to the bottom-right point `p2` and divide that by the distance between the two points. In `update()`, you can do this easily as `distance(p, p2) / distance(p1, p2)`. Store it in a global variable or write it to the DOM somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the image has no binding data.

I used `data` but @Ruben is right, `datum` will be more precise.

[drag the skier](https://jsfiddle.net/w9enas8j/7/)

```
const skier = svg
    .selectAll("#skier")
    .data([[0, 0]]) //
    .enter()
    .append('image')
    .attr('id', 'skier')
    .attr('href', skierIconSvg)
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .call(
        d3.drag()
          .subject(([x, y]) => ({ x, y }))
          .on('drag', dragged)
);
```

use `datum`

```
const skier = svg
    .append('image')
    .datum([0,0]) // use datum instead
    .attr('id', 'skier')
    .attr('href', skierIconSvg)
    .attr('width', 100)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .call(
        d3.drag()
          .subject(([x, y]) => ({ x, y }))
          .on('drag', dragged)
);
```